# ng-true-value and required in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type="checkbox" id="acknowledge" name="acknowledge" 
       ng-model="formData.acknowledge" 
       ng-true-value="true" 
       ng-required="formData.acknowledge !='true'"/>

<div ng-show="(peopleworksForm.acknowledge.$dirty || peopleworksForm.submited)  && formData.acknowledge !='true'">
   Please acknowledge that the information is correct</div>
```

I feel that something is wrong here with `ng-required`. Without `required` or `ng- required` it works fine. It returns the error message if I don't check the checkbox. But there also a problem: although I check the checkbox, `form.$valid = false`. That's why I tried using `required` or `ng-required`. You may asked me to remove the `ng-true-value` and use `required`. I know that also working. But the problem is I load `formData.acknowledge = "true"` inside my controller, so when the page loads the checkbox has to be checked. So I had to use `ng-true-value`. Can any one help me?

Comment: I tried fixing this question as much as I could to make the question more readable. Please edit it to provide answers to the following 2 (and **only** 2) questions: 1) what you want to achieve, 2) what happens now that is wrong.

Comment: if you removed "ng-required" it works nicely. But then although I diidnt tick the check box , "peopleworksForm.$valid" becomes TRUE. If I do like this (including ng-required) always the value of "formData.acknowledge" is FALSE. What I want is a normal validation behavior–

Comment: So, you want the form to be invalid for unchecked checkbox?

Comment: yes.. you are correct. But "ng-true-value" should be there..

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. Your truthy value is `"true"` - string, rather than `true` - boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restate, you want to show a message when the checkbox `acknowledge` is not checked by checking the `$valid` state of the form or the checkbox.

Also, the checkbox should be checked from the controller when assigned `"true"` - string value, rather than `true` - boolean value.

You are correct that you need to use `ng-true-value` to redefine the value given to the model for a checked state. You are using `ng-true-value` incorrectly, however, because you are not assigning the string value, but rather the boolean.

The correct way is below (notice the double-quotes `"' '"`):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo"
       ng-model="foo" ng-true-value="'true'" required>
```

In the controller you could assign to `"true"`:

```
$scope.foo = "true";
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/prqLbQk0QKg80nzYo7FT?p=preview)

Also, you don't need to use `ng-required` with an expression - this would make the control required on a conditional basis, and I think you want it to be always "required".

Comment: thnks a lot for the answer. In your plunket it is working nicely. But mine as soon as I put "ng-true-value"  $scope.foo=false always and $valid false. I cant understand what is wrong with this

Comment: @LasalSethiya, well, you need to either reproduce your issue, or rebuild based on my plunker.

Comment: <input id="declarationAcknowledgement" name="declarationAcknowledgement" ng-model="formData.declarationAcknowledgement" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-required="!formData.declarationAcknowledgement"   type="checkbox"/>


hello new dev - as you suggest it works in plunker even I applied my scenario there. But in my environment it returns always false(boolean value). As I have done above it works but if I only include ng-true-value it again returns false(boolean)always and so no matter I included that as above. then again there are two probs

Comment: 1)first time I check it returns ng-false value then works as normal. 2)what I really want to do is not to check "formData.declarationAcknowledgement" has value,does it equal to true.If I do so it again returns false (boolean)always

Comment: @LasalSethiya, what Angular version are you using? And, it seems again you are not setting `ng-true-value` correctly -  it should be `ng-true-value="'true'"` (with double and single quotes)

Comment: I also thinks that it's a problem with Angular version. I know that what you are telling. But its not working in ma machine.. No problem your solution is 100% correct and I found a new solution. Thnks a lot for your all efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

### General Pattern

You should be getting any data bindings you need from your controller.  If necessary, those pieces of data should come from a service you inject or depend on.  It sounds like you're roughly following that.

### ng-true-value

You should only need to use ng-true-value if you want something *other* than true or false, as that is [the default behavior](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D).

### what's probably wrong

In your controller, you should probably just be defaulting your property to `true` if that's what you need.

```
informationAcknowledgeOnlineRegistrationChange = true;  // replace value you get from your service
```

should do everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

As you have answer yourself, you can remove the ng-true-value and use the required:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="acknowledge" name="acknowledge" 
   ng-model="formData.acknowledge" 
   required />
<div ng-show="(peopleworksForm.acknowledge.$dirty || peopleworksForm.submited)  && formData.acknowledge">
Please acknowledge that the information is correct</div>
```

In the controller, the data binding would be:

```
formData.acknowledge = true; //not 'true' as string
```

Comment: the problem is I cant change the value set from controller.I want a solution from view side.. Otherwise I ll do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

when you don't check the check box no value is provided which goes against ng-required . here what you can do is to set a default value for for the check box when user doesn't provide any value for the checkbox